# Create bootable pendrive with distr

Tags: live-usb, kali

I want to create bootable pendrive (on Ubuntu) with other distr. I don't want to install this distr on my computer, rather plug a pendrive time to time and use this distr to the test and learning (like VirtualBox). I think about Kali Linux or Parrot. How I can do that?

Comment: You have a choice between a live (live-only) drive or persistent live drive. A live drive can be made with most cloning tools for example Disks alias `gnome-disks`. Persistent live drives or the two distros you mention (Kali and Parrot) can be made with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and mkusb can make live-only drives too (by cloning).

Comment: The following link about Parrot might be helpful, if you want something more than a live drive: [How do I install a live ISO on an SD card so it boots anywhere?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486921/how-do-i-install-a-live-iso-on-an-sd-card-so-it-boots-anywhere/487447#487447)

Answer (score 3):

### Create Bootable pendrive on Ubuntu

Gnome-disks has an option to "Restore Disk Image"

This option can be used to "restore" the ISO files of many distributions to a USB drive.

Open Disks, select the USB you want to install the ISO on, click the 3 lines icon upper right and select "Restore Disk Image". A window will open, just select the ISO file, confirm the destination and click start restoring.

If you want to make a Multi Boot USB, (with multiple OS on it), Both MultiBootUSB, (http://multibootusb.org/) and Ventoy, (https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html), have Linux versions. Both can make Persistent installs of Debian based OS, so that installed programs and data are retained from boot to boot.